# Facebook webhooks and rate limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

If my page or application hits rate limit as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting), what happens to webhooks? Will I continue receiving them? Official documentation has no information about this, also this is hard to reproduce.

Comment: since it´s not in your hands, i doubt that there is a limit. after all, facebook sends several responses in one call, if there many of them in a short timeframe, afaik.

Comment: Rate limits are about the API _calls_ your app makes; Webhooks are data sent _to you_ by Facebook.